# How to change a not nullable column to nullable in a Grails migration?

Tags: grails, database-migration

I need to change the columns currently not nullable to nullable using grails migration plugin. The dbm-gorm-diff command is throwing exception so what changeSet should I write to the changelog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Student
{
String Name
String LName
String MName

static constraints={

Name(nullablel:false,required:true)
Lname(nullable:false,required:true)
Mname(nullable:true,required:false)   
}

}
```

// by default if you dont specify nullable const it will always be nullable but assume we are going to generate migration scrip for this

//inside your script let say change Mname to nullable

```
databaseChangeLog = {

    changeSet(author: "developerName (generated)", id: "1369639981631-1") {
dropNotNullConstraint(columnDataType: "varchar(255)", columnName: "Mname", tableName: "student") 
 } 
     }
```

Answer (score -2):

I could just use the modifyDataType changeSet to achieve the desired result but in case if there is any other specific method for the same that is much welcome